# How do I handle custom types in Hibernate 6?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin

**Issue Summary**

I have a custom type that I use in a project with Spring Boot 2/Hibernate 5. I am attempting to migrate this project to Spring Boot 3/Hibernate 6 and I cannot seem to get this custom type to work. This type is a wrapper around a UUID, and should be treated as a UUID when reading/writing from/to a database.

**Existing Code**

My `TypedId` class allows for distinguishing different UUIDs based on the entity they are associated with. It's a relatively simple class:

```
data class TypedId<T>(val uuid: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()) : Serializable, Comparable<TypedId<T>> {
  constructor(id: String) : this(UUID.fromString(id))

  override fun compareTo(other: TypedId<T>): Int = this.uuid.compareTo(other.uuid)

  override fun toString(): String = uuid.toString()
}
```

This is configured in a base DatabaseRecord abstract class that all my JPA Entities extend:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@TypeDef(defaultForType = TypedId::class, typeClass = TypedIdJpaType::class)
abstract class DatabaseRecord<T> : Persistable<TypedId<T>> {
    @Id var uid: TypedId<T> = TypedId()
    @Transient private var innerIsNew: Boolean = true
    override fun getId(): TypedId<T> = uid

    override fun isNew(): Boolean = innerIsNew

    private fun handleIsNew() {
        innerIsNew = false
    }

    @PrePersist
    open fun onPrePersist() {
        handleIsNew()
    }

    @PostLoad
    open fun onPostLoad() {
        handleIsNew()
    }
}
```

The important part of the above code is the `@TypeDef`. That points to the JPA Type class that configures the entire type definition. Here is the relevant code pulled in by that annotation:

```
class TypedIdJpaType :
    AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<TypedId<*>>(
        PostgresUUIDSqlTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, TypedIdDescriptor.INSTANCE) {
  override fun getName(): String = TypedId::class.java.simpleName
  override fun registerUnderJavaType(): Boolean = true
}

class TypedIdDescriptor : AbstractTypeDescriptor<TypedId<*>>(TypedId::class.java) {
  companion object {
    val INSTANCE = TypedIdDescriptor()
  }
  override fun fromString(string: String): TypedId<*> = TypedId<Any>(string)

  override fun <X : Any> wrap(value: X?, options: WrapperOptions): TypedId<*>? =
      value?.let { nonNullValue ->
        when (nonNullValue) {
          is ByteArray ->
              TypedId(UUIDTypeDescriptor.ToBytesTransformer.INSTANCE.parse(nonNullValue))
          is String ->
              TypedId<Any>(UUIDTypeDescriptor.ToStringTransformer.INSTANCE.parse(nonNullValue))
          is UUID -> TypedId<Any>(nonNullValue)
          else -> throw unknownWrap(nonNullValue::class.java)
        }
      }

  override fun <X : Any> unwrap(value: TypedId<*>, type: Class<X>, options: WrapperOptions): X =
      UUIDTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE.unwrap(value.uuid, type, options)
}
```

Lastly, here is my sample entity that I have created for very basic test cases involving all of this code:

```
interface CountryId

@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
class Country(var name: String = "") : DatabaseRecord<CountryId>()
```

**The Core Problem**

With Hibernate 6, `@TypeDef`, `TypeDescriptor`, etc are all removed. This means the entire mechanism for converting the `TypedId` no longer works. I've been trying to identify an alternate solution.

**The Question**

I've tried a `Converter`. I've tried implementing `AbstractStandardBasicType`. I'm just very lost right now.

I've been reading over the new Hibernate 6 user guide, but nothing I've gleaned from there has helped yet.

**Additional Details**

After posting this question, I realized the error message should be useful. This happens when I try to use a Spring `JpaRepository` to save (aka insert) the above entity:

```
could not execute statement [ERROR: column "uid" is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow, this was quite the rabbit hole. So, a few quick findings for the group. It seems that Hibernate is moving away from the `AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType` approach for type definitions. Even after I got it implemented properly, registering it was a nightmare. The primary issue with registering it was that every option that still exists in Hibernate 6 seems to be marked for deprecation. Basically that whole approach was a dead-end.

The `AttributeConverter` approach also doesn't seem to work for more complex types like my `TypedId`. I could never get Hibernate to recognize it.

In the end, I discovered that using the `@JavaType` and `@JdbcType` mechanisms Hibernate 6 offers in tandem was the solution.

First, I needed to write a `JavaType` implementation, which was easy since my type is just a wrapper around `UUID`:

```
class TypedIdJavaType:
    AbstractClassJavaType<TypedId<*>>(TypedId::class.java) {
  override fun <X : Any?> unwrap(value: TypedId<*>?, type: Class<X>, options: WrapperOptions?): X =
      UUIDJavaType.INSTANCE.unwrap(value?.uuid, type, options)

  override fun <X : Any?> wrap(value: X, options: WrapperOptions?): TypedId<*> =
      TypedId<Any>(UUIDJavaType.INSTANCE.wrap(value, options))
}
```

Then, I reference my new `JavaType` via the annotation on my `uid` property. However, I also need to include the `@JdbcType(UUIDJdbcType::class)` as well. See below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@TypeDef(defaultForType = TypedId::class, typeClass = TypedIdJpaType::class)
abstract class DatabaseRecord<T> : Persistable<TypedId<T>> {
    @Id 
    @JavaType(TypedIdJavaType::class)
    @JdbcType(UUIDJdbcType::class)
    var uid: TypedId<T> = TypedId()
    @Transient private var innerIsNew: Boolean = true
    override fun getId(): TypedId<T> = uid

    override fun isNew(): Boolean = innerIsNew

    private fun handleIsNew() {
        innerIsNew = false
    }

    @PrePersist
    open fun onPrePersist() {
        handleIsNew()
    }

    @PostLoad
    open fun onPostLoad() {
        handleIsNew()
    }
}
```

The reason for needing both appears to be that `@JdbcType` tells Hibernate what this field is supposed to be when it is first scanning the entity. Once it knows what type it is supposed to be via `@JdbcType`, it then checks the other annotations, Hibernate's configuration, etc to find an available mechanism for converting the provided type to the JDBC Type.

And that's it. This was a massive rabbit hole that IMO is not well documented at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the great summary - you helped me better understand the new method of custom type / jdbc type registration.
Do you also have an idea, how can I make the @GeneratedValue work for a custom type ? It seems that during Identity Generation hibernate does not know how to handle my custom type:

 Unknown integral data type for ids : com.example.generated_embeded_key.CompanyPK

Comment: For non-complex types, attribute converter is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by craigmiller160, the documentation for custom user types in Hibernate 6 is not well documented. Hopefully this improves in the future.

I had a similar setup (using custom domain object as entity ID) but in addition was using an IdentifierGenerator:

```
public class UserAccountIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object)
    throws HibernateException {
        return new UserAccountId(UUID.randomUUID());
    }
}
```

Note that the type of the return value has to be of the domain object. Otherwise Hibernate throws an (unhelpful) error like so:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set value of type [java.lang.String] : `com.mtc.app.UserAccount.id` (setter)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set value of type [java.lang.String] : `com.mtc.app.UserAccount.id` (setter)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.mtc.app.UserAccountId field com.mtc.app.UserAccount.id to java.lang.String
```