# How does Hibernate's custom type mapping (AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType) work in Hibernate 6?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm a student working on a fairly simple CRUD web application using Spring Boot, Hibernate and Swagger UI. I was thinking of saving a List field into my Account table as a single column, as

1. there is no need to query based on this field
2. it does not need to be accessed separately from the Account entity
3. it does not need individual items within to be accessed, only created, read or deleted as a whole i.e. no performance incentive from using a separate Entity

I tried to follow two articles that suggested using AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType, from [Thorben Janssen](https://thorben-janssen.com/collections-hibernate-jpa/#:%7E:text=much%20better%20performance.-,Map%20a%20Collection%20as%20a%20Basic%20Type,-Hibernate%20can%20map) and from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types), but both used AbstractTypeDescriptor, which (after some time of searching) I determined was no longer part of Hibernate from the 6.0 release onward. This brings me to the question: how is AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType meant to be used in Hibernate's latest version and is custom object single column mapping still possible?

Note, I did try to work through the documentation at docs.jboss.org and could not make sense of it. I didn't like the idea of using @ElementCollection because of the extra table generated, which seemed unnecessary for my use case, but will do so for the sake of a working implementation.

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76418374/how-do-i-handle-custom-types-in-hibernate-6) question about the same problem and lack of clarity, but as I don't know Kotlin and that question was about UUID rather than a List, I didn't get much from it.